# Modify LOF- and LOT-Style in KOMA-Script scrreprt

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, tocbasic

I have modified my TOC with `\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[beforeskip=.2cm]{section}{section}` giving me a nice spacing between my section level entries.

How can I modify the spacing between entries in the LOF and LOT with KOMA-Script?
(Or maybe wider the styling of other `listof` in general?)

I have tried to find it in the documentation but start to fail at understanding wheather KOMA even applies to other `listof`.

Answer (score 1):

To modify the List of Figure and List of Tables you can use

`\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[Option=Value]{tocline}{table}`

`\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[Option=Value]{tocline}{figure}`

Comment: You could also use `\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[Option=Value]{tocline}{figure,table}`. If `beforeskip` should be the same for `section`, `table` and `figure`: `\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[beforeskip=.2cm]{tocline}{section,figure,table}`. See the document for more information.